# Ruby Date Subtraction (e.g. 90 days Ago)

Tags: ruby, date

I've been a bit spoiled by the joda-time API of:

```
DateTime now = new DateTime();
DateTime ninetyDaysAgo = now.minusDays(90);
```

I'm trying to do a similar thing in Ruby, but I'm

```
now = Time.now
ninetyDaysAgo = now - (90*24)
```

However, the math is off here (I'm really working with dates at midnight).

Is there friendly API for date subtraction?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

```
require 'date'
now = Date.today
ninety_days_ago = (now - 90)
```

Running this thru the IRB console I get:

```
>>require 'date'
now = Date.today
ninety_days_ago = (now - 90)

require 'date'
=> false
now = Date.today
=> #<Date: 2011-03-02 (4911245/2,0,2299161)>
ninety_days_ago = (now - 90)
=> #<Date: 2010-12-02 (4911065/2,0,2299161)>
```

If you need the time you could just say `now = DateTime.now`

Comment: Your original post, pre-edit was closer to what I needed, but Date.Now was protected.  Date.today worked.  If you change your first blurb to have the line now = Date.today, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Matt: and how to subtract 90 hours instead of days?

Comment: @EstebanFeldman `Date` also allows fractions so you can do `Date.today - (90.0/24.0)`. The result can easily be converted `to_datetime` or `to_time` too.

Answer (score 21):

For those using Rails, check out the following:

```
DateTime.now - 10.days
=> Sat, 04 May 2013 12:12:07 +0300

20.days.ago - 10.days
=> Sun, 14 Apr 2013 09:12:13 UTC +00:00
```

Answer (score 10):

If you're using Rails or don't mind including ActiveSupport, you can use the [Numeric#days](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html#method-i-days) DSL like this:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 > Date.today
 => Wed, 02 Mar 2011 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :003 > Date.today - 90.days
 => Thu, 02 Dec 2010
```

Since you are working with dates instead of times, you should also either start with Date instances, or convert your DateTime intances with #to_date.  When adding/subtracting numbers from date instances, the numbers are implicitly days.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :016 > DateTime.now.to_date
 => #<Date: 2011-03-02 (4911245/2,0,2299161)> 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :017 > DateTime.now.to_date - 90
 => #<Date: 2010-12-02 (4911065/2,0,2299161)>
```

Answer (score 10):

Ruby supports date arithmetic in the [Date and DateTime classes](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html), which are part of Ruby's standard library. Both those classes expose [#+](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-2B) and [#-](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-2D) methods, which add and subtract days from a date or a time.

```
$ irb
 > require 'date'
 => true 
 > (DateTime.new(2015,4,1) - 90).to_s  # Apr 1, 2015 - 90 days
 => "2015-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"
 > (DateTime.new(2015,4,1) - 1).to_s   # Apr 1, 2015 - 1 day
 => "2015-03-31T00:00:00+00:00"
```

Use the [#<<](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3C-3C) and [#>>](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3E-3E) methods to operate on months instead of days. Arithmetic on months is a little different than arithmetic on days. Using Date instead of DateTime makes the effect more obvious.

```
 > (Date.new(2015, 5, 31) << 3).to_s  # May 31 - 3 months; 92 days diff
 => "2015-02-28"
```

Following your joda-time example, you might write something like this in Ruby.

```
now =  DateTime.now
ninety_days_ago = now - 90
```

or maybe just

```
ninety_days_ago = DateTime.now - 90
```

Answer (score 9):

use the number of seconds:

```
Time.now - 90*24*60*60
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a super old post, but if you wanted to keep with a `Time` object, like was originally asked, rather than switching to a `Date` object you might want to consider using `Ruby Facets`.

Ruby Facets is a standardized library of extensions for core Ruby classes.

http://rubyworks.github.io/facets/

By requiring Facets you can then do the following with Time objects.

`Time.now.less(90, :days)`

Comment: This project hasn't been updated for two years and has opened issues with a single comment. It's dead.

Comment: @user4674453 The last update was six months ago.  It's a stable library that still works with the latest version of Ruby.  Not all codebases need to be updated daily in order to not be considered "dead".

Answer (score 0):

Gem install chronic

```
require 'chronic'
$wdate = Chronic.parse '7 days ago'
```

Answer (score -2):

Simple solution using Rails Active Support:

```
days90_ago = 90.days.ago.to_date.to_s

OUTPUT:
puts 90_days_ago
=> "2019-10-09" # considering cur_date: 2020-01-07
```

Comment: This is using ActiveSupport (Rails).